# I want to replace battery on my Acer Aspire ES1-111 and I'm having hard time choosing batteries online

Tags: battery-charging, identification, high-voltage, laptop, replacement

-My original battery is AC14B13J---TYP3220mAh/36Wh---MIN3090mAh/34.5Wh---11.4V 3140mAh

-The one I found online has the same description as my original battery, but it has an 11.55V 3180mAh. Is it okay to replace it with this kind of higher volts?

-The other one has a different ID (I will call it ID because I don't know what it stands for), which is AC14B18J but the TYP, MIN, and V are the same as the original. Should I be cautious with the different ID AC14B18J even though the online said it is compatible with AC14B13J? Because I worry that it might differ in size.

Comment: Ah, 11.4V and 11.55V differs by only 0.15V.  It should be within spec.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the question is completely ontopic, but anyway:

A LiIon battery made of 3 cells in series will have nominal voltage of 11.1 or 11.4 or something up to 12.8 but it is essentially the same.

The actual battery voltage will vary from 9.0 (or somewhat below) all the way to 12.6 (or somewhat higher) depending on the state of charge (SOC) of the battery.

Manufacturers choose different intermediate voltages (usually, but not always) closer to the middle of the range in order to label the battery. The only role of this "nominal" voltage is to state that the battery is 3S type (3 cells in series).

In short, there is no real difference between 11.4V and 11.55V li-ion battery other than the manufacturer's labeling choice.

You have to use other clues to determine which battery is better for you.